# browser extension - customize ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT window

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, browser-extension

Is possible to replace the `ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT` displayed window with an image that is injected with a content script of a browser extension? I'm using the `webRequests` API to block some websites and I want to show to the user a customized `ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT` window instead of the default one of the browser.